# Port forwarding command

Tags: linux, command, portforwarding

I'm trying to do a port forwarding with ssh using this command:

```
ssh -L 9540:localhost:8011 user@ipdest
```

The port is for HTTPS traffic, I’m not getting any kind of error  when I run the command, actually I get the ssh connection  to the  destination IP.

The problem is that when I try to connect with the browser to the URL `localhost:9540` it doesn’t show anything, I’m not able to reach the HTTPS service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please  check   the  sshd config   file with the below command and make sure that the lines in bold are like the  example?

```
more  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

#AllowAgentForwarding yes

**AllowTcpForwarding yes**

#GatewayPorts no

X11Forwarding yes

#X11DisplayOffset 10

#X11UseLocalhost yes

#PermitTTY yes

PrintMotd no

#PrintLastLog yes

#TCPKeepAlive yes

#PermitUserEnvironment no

#Compression delayed

#ClientAliveInterval 0

#ClientAliveCountMax 3

#UseDNS no

#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid

#MaxStartups 10:30:100

**PermitTunnel yes**

#ChrootDirectory none

#VersionAddendum none

If not please  set the lines  as the  example and restart  the sshd service, try  to connect  again and test  your tunnel again.